# Use lapply to multiply two lists of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply, matrix-multiplication

I have two lists, each one with many matrices. For brevity, here is an example with two matrices per list:

```
l1 <- list(matrix(1:20, nrow=2),
           matrix(21:40, nrow=2))

l2 <- list(matrix(41:60, nrow=2),
           matrix(61:80, nrow=2))
```

I am trying to use `lapply` to (a) remove the first column of each matrix and then (b) multiply each matrix in `l1` against the corresponding matrix in `l2`.

First, I tried:

```
result <- lapply(l1, function(x,y){
  
  tmp <- x[,-1]*y[,-1]
  return(tmp)
  
}, y=l2)
```

It didn't work. The problem is that I can't remove the first column from `l2` this way. If `l2` were a vector instead of a list, the code would work with `tmp <- x[,-1]*y[-1]`. But even when I try to simply multiply the matrices in each list, it still does not work:

```
result <- lapply(l1, function(x,y){
  
  tmp <- x*y
  return(tmp)
  
}, y=l2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lapply`, you can iterate over only one object. You may use `Map` here -

```
Map(function(x, y)  x[,-1]*y[,-1], l1, l2)

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]  129  225  329  441  561  689  825  969 1121
#[2,]  176  276  384  500  624  756  896 1044 1200

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,] 1449 1625 1809 2001 2201 2409 2625 2849 3081
#[2,] 1536 1716 1904 2100 2304 2516 2736 2964 3200
```

To use `lapply` you may use the index to subset both `l1` and `l2`.

```
lapply(seq_along(l1), function(x) l1[[x]][, -1] * l2[[x]][, -1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(l1, l2, ~ .x[, -1] * .y[,-1])
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]  129  225  329  441  561  689  825  969 1121
[2,]  176  276  384  500  624  756  896 1044 1200

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] 1449 1625 1809 2001 2201 2409 2625 2849 3081
[2,] 1536 1716 1904 2100 2304 2516 2736 2964 3200
```